# Javascript Web components Setter not called for nested components

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component

Suppose I have the following child element:

```js
class ChildElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._value = 0;
  }

  set value(newValue) {
    this._value = newValue;
    this.render();
    console.log("Value was updated")
  }

  get value() {
    return this._value
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.render();
  }

  render() {
    this.innerHTML = `<p>This element has value <strong>${this._value}</strong></p>`
  }
}

customElements.define("child-element", ChildElement);
```

`_value` is set to an integer here for simplicity, but in general I can have a more complex object, which is why I prefer to work with properties instead of attributes.

For simplicity, its sole goal is to displays its `_value` property, initially set to zero. The idea is that, every time `value` is changed (e.g., from another component), it is re-rendered just like a data binding.

Apart from using the `<child-element></child-element>`, I know I can initialize this element like:

```js
// Initialization with default value 0
const child = document.createElement("child-element");
document.body.appendChild(child); 

// Initialization with different value 5
const child = document.createElement("child-element");
child.value = 5;
document.body.appendChild(child);
```

and every time I change its value with `child.value = newValue` it gets properly re-rendered.

However, say I have a parent element:

```js
class ParentElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<child-element></child-element>`
    this.querySelector("child-element").value = 5;  // setter is not called
  }
}

customElements.define("parent-element", ParentElement);
```

(I know it looks useless here but in principle it can be used to create multiple children from an array of values, which can be updated and be used to re-render them, for example)

The problem is that the setter of the child is never called and its HTML is never updated. Even if I manually query the child from the parent nothing happens:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector("parent-element");
const child = parent.querySelector("child-element");
child.value = 10;  // does not trigger the `setter`
```

If I inspect `child` I can see that `child.value` is now `10`, but `child._value` is still 0.

I tried replacing the line `this.innerHTML = <child-element></child-element>` with a manual `createElement("child-element")` but still no luck.

However, I noticed that, if I remove the `this.querySelector("child-element").value = 10;` line from the `connectedCallback`, the setter starts begin called and the previous code works.

So, does anyone know what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **only possibility** this can happen is that your web component is possibly in a limbo state i.e. **unknown tags** stage. This happens when your code that's responsible for calling setters on `ChildElement` is being executed before the component is registered in a registry.

For example, if you have following sequence of code, then setter would not be called:

```
function main() {
  
  document.body.innerHTML = '<parent-element></parent-element>';
  const parent = document.querySelector('parent-element');
  const child = parent.querySelector('child-element');
  child.value = 10;

  // Child element defined after invoking the setter...
  customElements.define('child-element', ChildElement);
}

main();
```

Custom elements go through something called as [upgrade process](https://web.dev/custom-elements-v1/#element-upgrades). So it is not an error when you call the element's setter before it is defined or upgraded. Thus, when you say:

> *If I inspect child I can see that child.value is now 10, but child._value is still 0.*

It simply means that it created an element of type `HTMLElement` and you simply added a property called `value` with `10` on it which overrides `value` setter or getter that you create in the `ChildElement` class.

Comment: For this purpose there is a `customElements.whenDefined( "child-element" )` method to see if your tag name is ready to be used before you start interacting with it. (Which I know is a bit useless in `sync` methods)

Comment: Exactly. Even though, promises are meant to be executed as microtasks, `wheDefined` doesn't behave like one.

Comment: That makes sense! I thought that by assigning `value` inside the `connectedCallback` I would have no such problem.

So I tried @somethinghere's suggestion wrapping the assignment with

`customElements.whenDefined("child-element").then(() => this.querySelector("child-element").value = 5)`

and it worked well.

Thank you both for the answers!